# How do I access the nested Class?

Tags: c#

I have the following three classes defined.

```
public class FrequencyRecord
{
    public double Frequency;
    public int Duration;
}

public class EntryRecord
{
    public string Name;
    public Boolean Status;
    public long TotalTime;
    public FrequencyRecord[] FreqTime = new FrequencyRecord[25];
    public string Description;
}

public class Salv7Profile
{
    public string Version;
    public string SoftVersion;
    public string Name;
    public DateTime CreateDate;
    public DateTime LastModDate;
    public int Count;
    public EntryRecord[] Entries = new EntryRecord[99];
    public int Type;                         
}
```

Then I create an instance:

```
public static Salv7Profile IntProfile = new Salv7Profile();
```

Assigning a value to:

```
IntProfile.Name = "Peter";
```

works fine, But if I try:

```
IntProfile.Entries[1].Name = "Peter";
```

It throws an error: [System.NullReferenceException] "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Being a novice at C#, how do I access the nested Entries class?

Comment: A "nested" class would be a `class` defined *within* another class.

Comment: you can use [`struct EntryRecord`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx) instead of `class`

Comment: @Grundy: Yes, but then the OP would have a large mutable struct... hardly a better situation, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet yep, it just another way :-)

Comment: @JonSkeet, maybe have the opportunity to call the default constructor for the elements when creating arrays?

Comment: @Grundy: Not unless you use `Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => new EntryRecord()).ToArray()` or something similar.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you've created an array, but that array is just full of null references to start with. You'd need something like:

```
EntryRecord record = new EntryRecord();
record.Name = "Peter";
IntProfile.Entries[1] = record;
```

to replace the array element with a reference to the newly-created `EntryRecord`.

It would almost certainly be better if you changed `Entries` to be a `List<EntryRecord>` though, and just used:

```
EntryRecord record = new EntryRecord();
record.Name = "Peter";
IntProfile.Entries.Add(record);
```

or more briefly, using an object initialzier:

```
IntProfile.Entries.Add(new EntryRecord { Name = "Peter" });
```

I would also *strongly* recommend against having public fields; use properties instead, and consider making your types immutable if you can.

(I'd encourage to think about whether you *really* need the `IntProfile` field to be static, too... static fields imply global state, which is harder to test and reason about.)